# What devices support geolocation speed reading in their browsers?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, geolocation

I am experimenting with the GeoLocation speed reading on mobile device browsers, and it would be great if there existed list of devices that support it. Searching didn't help a lot.

So far, I've tested a few Android 2.3 (those I tried give an accurate speed reading), IPhone 3 and 3G (both return null), IPad (returns null). What I'm more interested in, is this tied to the API implementation or the gps hardware in the device? Also, does IPhone 4 support the coords.speed reading?

Comment: NB: you could always fake this by taking multiple location readings, and doing the math. It will be imprecise though.

Comment: Already tried that. While it works in some cases, most times the accuracy is just bad - with errors as big as four kilometers in the distance, making the speed error even worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [spec](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#speed), an implementation must return `null` if speed reading is not supported. Seems like they do that, but some people on the internet say the iOS browser implemented the `speed` API, at least in `watchPosition`, see eg. [these](http://www.thedotproduct.org/2010/04/accurate-geo-location-from-apple-iphone-using-navigator-geolocation/) [pages](http://blog.geigel.com/2010/06/html5-geolocation-on-iphone/).

From the spec, I would also assume that you cannot reliably tell whether a `null` value means 'No API support' or 'No GPS support'. It could mean either.

In any case, I think you're better off implementing fallbacks and a user-friendly notice the device isn't giving you any information, rather than whitelisting/blacklisting... based on what? UA strings aren't everything, especially not what with Android's ability to have alternative browsers (eg. Firefox Mobile, Opera, ...).